# Proof of $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$ is fulfilled when it is true for $n = 2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Prove that for given elements $a,b$ from group $G$, equation $(ab)^n = a^nb^n$ is fulfilled for all $n∈ {\displaystyle \mathbb {Z} }, $ if and only if equation is true for $ n=2 $.

I have no idea how to prove it. I would be gratefulfor any help.

Comment: $(ab)^2=a^2b^2$ is equivalent to $ab=ba$ in $G$; multiply by $a^{-1}$ from the left and by $b^{-1}$ from the right.

Comment: If it holds for $n=2$, then $abab=a^2b^2$. Multiplying $a^{-1}$ from the left and $b^{-1}$ from the right gives $ba = ab$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I haven't known that these two conditions are  equivalent ("the same").